# force login page before index

Tags: php, html

I have a login form that displays a message when a user either registers or logins in. I would like the login page to open first and after successful login then index.php can be shown. also should someone try and access  /index.php directly it must still direct them to login.php to be authenticated. I have tried some examples of other peoples codes but i cannot get the page to authenticate the user.

My Login.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once('connect.php');
if(isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)){
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['username']);
$password = md5($_POST['password']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($count == 1){
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}else{
    $fmsg = "Invalid Username/Password";
}
}
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$smsg = "User already logged in";
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>User Login in PHP & MySQL</title>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <?php if(isset($smsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"> <?php echo $smsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
  <?php if(isset($fmsg)){ ?><div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> <?php echo $fmsg; ?> </div><?php } ?>
  <form class="form-signin" method="POST">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Register</h2>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required>
    </div>
    <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholde r="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Login</button>
    <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" href="register.php">Register</a>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Don't use `md5()` for password hashing.** It's very insecure. Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. If you're running a PHP version lower than 5.5 (which I _really_ hope you aren't), you can use the [password_compat library](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) to get the same functionallity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can if statement to check whether user is login or not.
If user is not logged in then you can redirect them to login.php 
If user is logged in then you can let them see index page. 
To do so, code example is given below....

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    $welcomeMessage = "Welcome to the member's area, " . $_SESSION['username'] . "!";
} else {
    header('Location: login.php');
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Index page</title>  
</head>
<body>
<?
    if(!empty($welcomeMessage)) echo $welcomeMessage;
?>
 Index page
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @J.Hof you can put your entire code after welcome message. like.....
echo "Welcome to the member's area, " . $_SESSION['username'] . "!";  
Rest of the code here

Comment: and i put this on my login.php or index.php page sir?

Comment: you will put this code in your index page. if user is visiting for the first time then user will be redirected to login page. if user is already logged in then script will allow them to see index page

Answer (score 0):

*I would like the login page to open first and after successful login then index.php can be shown.*

Well you could create a .htaccess file then add this line:

`DirectoryIndex  login.php`  when someone visits your site will go to login.php

then on login.php

first check if that user is not loggedin already

therefore **login.php**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('connect.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
$smsg = "User already logged in";
header("location:index.php"); // send to index if logged in
}else{

    // the code you have in your question here


}
?>
```

*also should someone try and access /index.php directly it must still direct them to login.php to be authenticated.* You would need to check if the session is set or not if its set continue or send them back to login

**index.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])):?>



    Your html content

<?php

    else:

    header("location:login.php");//send them to login

    endif;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The absolute easiest way (according to me) would be to create a new file called `auth.php` with the following content:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['username'])) {
    // The username session key does not exist or it's empty.
    header('location: /login.php');
    exit;
}
```

Then, in the very top of every page you want to protect (including your index.php), just add:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/auth.php';
?>

// Continue with your HTML here
```

No need to build the sites inside `if/else`-statements.

***Note:** This assumes that all your pages are in the root folder. If you have other pages in sub folders that you want to protect, you need to add the correct path to `auth.php`, since `__DIR__` gives you the absolute path of the file you write it in.*